# No Json serializer found for type Seq[Foo]

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have a class and a companion object defined as follows:

```scala
case class Foo(
  bar: String,
  baz: String,
)

object Foo {
  implicit val format = Json.format[Foo]
}
```

And when trying to compile this code, I get an error:

```scala
val example: Seq[Foo] = Seq()
val json = Json.toJson(example)
```

```
No Json serializer found for type Seq[Foo]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
```

As far as I can tell, I have an implicit Format. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `implicit val format = Json.format[Foo]` is not a `Format[Foo]`.

Comment: Change that line in the companion to: `implicit val format: Format[Foo] = Json.format[Foo]` - then the compiler should tell you what is wrong.

Comment: @MartinHH Adding `Format[Foo]` fixed it! Thank you! If you make it an answer I will accept

Comment: Ok, made an answer out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `implicit val format = Json.format[Foo]` is not a `Format[Foo]`.

Change that line in the companion to: `implicit val format: Format[Foo] = Json.format[Foo]` - then the compiler should tell you what is wrong.